# How to increase google SQL read ops limit?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently using Google Cloud SQL for MySQL
but when I do a heavy query it gets read ops above the limit and then the query gets cancelled.
How to increase this read ops limit?
I'm using a SSD with 50 GB of storage.

[image: read ops limit]

Thank you.

Comment: Let's work on shrinking the data or adding a useful index or reformulating the query or ... -- in order to avoid the limit.  Show us the query, its `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: If the quota is for persistent disk IOPS then increase the size of the disk to increase the read quota. Otherwise, clarify your question with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon your graph, your disk read quota is about 1500 IOPS.

Persistent disk performance is related to provisioned size. Google Cloud SQL SSD Zonal and Regional Persistent Disks receive 30 read and 30 write IOPS per GB.

For a 50 GB SSD PS - 50 * 30 = 1500.

To increase the read and write performance, resize the disk larger. This is easily performed in the Google Cloud Console GUI by editing the instance configuration **Storage capacity**. Resizing does not cause downtime.

The chart shows a peak of about 3500 IOPS. Resize the 50 GB SSD to 120 GB.

Note: disks also have a quota for MB/sec. SSD has a quota of 0.48 MB/sec per GB. Increasing the disk size will also increase the speed of data transfers.

[Block Storage Performance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance)